# How to read local.properties file inside setting.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

before this, we used this code in *build.gradle* but after Gradle updated repositories moved to *setting.gradle*. currently, I don't know how to read properties inside the *setting.gradle* file.

```
def propFile = rootProject.file("./local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

ext.alias = properties['mavenprivate.alias']
ext.key = properties['mavenprovate.key']
```

and using them for maven repo:

```
credentials {
   username = alias
   password = key
}
```

I got this error:

> Could not get unknown property 'alias' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

Android-studio Arctic fox, Gradle 7.0.2

Comment: how you sulved?